# Is $\prod_{1\leq i< j\leq n} \frac{a_i - a_j}{i-j}$, with distinct integers $a_i$, an integer?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, geometry, number-theory

It is known that for every $n$ consecutive integers, their product is divisible by $n!$, since $${{m}\choose{n}} = \frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}$$ is also an integer.

So is it true that for every distinct integer $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$, the number $$S = \prod_{1\leq i< j\leq n} \frac{a_i - a_j}{i-j}$$ is also an integer?

(Sorry for my grammar mistakes, English is my second language)

Comment: What will happen If each $a_i$ is a multiple of some prime $p>n$?

Comment: @JensSchwaiger I think the problem is still true i guess? I have tried with 4,5,6,7 and it satisfied that $S$ was an integer.

Comment: Forget my previous comment. I mixed up nominator and denominator. Probably still tired.

Comment: For what it's worth, the conjecture is true for all $n\leq 7$, and I'm having a devil of a time finding counter-examples with simulations for larger $n$.

Answer (score 15):

We observe that $\prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} (i-j) = \prod_{r=1}^n r!$ and the numerator is just the Vandermonde Determinant so that by performing row operations we obtain
$$\prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \frac{a_i-a_j}{i-j} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
\binom{a_1}{1} & \binom{a_2}{1} & \cdots & \binom{a_n}{1} \\
\binom{a_1}{2} & \binom{a_2}{2} & \cdots & \binom{a_n}{2} \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\binom{a_1}{n-1} & \binom{a_2}{n-1} & \cdots & \binom{a_n}{n-1} \\
\end{vmatrix}$$

which is obviously an integer.

Comment: I don't see how the  first relation holds: $\prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq 2} (i - j) = (1 - 2) = -1 \neq 1! \times 2!$

Comment: I think that $\prod_{r=1}^n r!$ should be $\pm \prod_{r=1}^{n-1} r!$.  But apart from that, the proof works. Notice how on the $r+1$'th row you have $a_1^r/r!$ plus lower powers of $a_1$, but those lower powers can be row-reduced away using previous rows. This means that after row-reduction you get a Vandermonde matrix with the $r+1$'th row divided by $r!$. So you get the determinant of the Vandermonde matrix, divided by  $\prod_{r=1}^{n-1} r!$. With that being an integer, the result follows.

Comment: I believe this is what people call a proof from the book. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Let $q = p^k$ for some prime $p$ and integer $k>0$. If you let $n_q$ = the number of pairs $i<j$ for which $a_i - a_j$ is divisible by $q$, then notice that $n_q$ is minimized for $a_1,\ldots,a_n = 1,2,\ldots,n$   (it is a bit of work to show this but it is not deep) (basically, you consider the set $\mathbb{Z}/(q)$ and now you look the function $f: \mathbb{Z}/(q) \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ for which $f(a)$ is the number of $i$ for which $a_i$ mod $q$ is $a$.  Then observe that you can compute $n_q$ from $f$, and that $n_q$ is minimized if all values of $f$ are inside $\{m,m+1\}$ where $m$ is $n/q$ rounded down).

Now apply this for $q = p, p^2, p^3, \ldots$ and you see that the $p$-adic valuation of the numerator of $S$ is at least that of the denominator. That means $S$ is an integer.