# Is there a more elegant answer to proving $\prod_{0\le i<j\le n-1}\frac{a_{j}-a_{i}}{j-i}$ is integer given $a_i$ is integer for $0\le i \le n-1$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

A friend sent me this problem and I couldn't find a solution online. I'm wondering if my attempt is correct and whether if there is a more elegant solution?

The Problem:
Suppose that $a_0, a_1, ... a_{n-1} $ are $n$ integers. Show that the following product
$$ P(a_0,a_1,...,a_{n-1}) = \prod _{0\le i<j\le n-1}^{ }\frac{a_j-a_i}{j-i}\ \qquad(1)$$
is integer.

My Attempt:
We will prove this with induction and an application of the pigeonhole principle

Base case: $n=1$

$$P(a_0,a_1) = \frac{a_1 - a_0}{1-0}$$
is clearly integer as $1-0 = 1$ and $a_1,a_0 \in \mathbb{N}$

We now assume $n=k$
Assume $P(a_0, ... , a_{k-1}) \in \mathbb{N}$

Note that 
$$P(a_0, ... , a_{k}) = P(a_0, ... , a_{k-1}) \cdot \prod _{0\le i \le k-1}^{ }\frac{a_k-a_i}{k-i}\ \qquad (2)$$

For any fixed $0 \le i \le k-1$, we see that it is possible that $k-i \not| \ a_k - a_i$, and then resulting in the product on the right of (2) being non-integer.

Specifically, we observe that the product on the right of (2) is non integer if the following occurs

$$a_k\ \text{mod}\ (k-i) \not\cong a_j \qquad (3)$$

For all $0 \le j \not= i \le k-1$

Note that as $0 \le i \le k-1$, then $1 \le k-i \le k$, meaning that the complete residual class of $k-i$ is at a maximum, $\{0, 1, 2, ..., k - 1\}$, $k$ possible distinct residuals.

Consider the $P(a_0, ... , a_{k-1})$ in (2)

By the definition of $P$ in (1), we see that for every unique permutation of the set $\{c,d\}$ corresponding to the term $\frac{a_c-a_d}{c-d}$ for $0 \le c<d \le k-i$ exists in $P(a_0, ... , a_{k-1})$.

Additionally, due to (3), we have that $a_c, a_d$ can have a possible $k-1$ distinct residuals at most, with one being the residual of $a_k\ \text{mod}\ (k-i)$

But note that $P(a_0, ... , a_{k-1})$ uses $k$ variables $a_0, a_1, ..., a_{k-1}$, so therefore by the pigeonhole principle, there must be one term in that product that results in $$k-i \ | \ a_c - a_d$$

Otherwise similar stated by saying that $a_c - a_d \ \text{mod} \ k - i\cong 0$

Thus, we show that for any $0\le i \le k-1$, the product on the right of $(2)$ will still evaluate to be an integer. Thus (2) is integral as we also assumed that $P(a_0, ..., a_{k-1})$ is integer.

Thus, by the induction principle, (1) must be true.

I'm not sure if this is a valid formal proof, also am wondering if there are better solutions.

Comment: You can write the product as a Vandermonde determinant with integer entries. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1085531, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2899169, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/105348.

Comment: From a quick look, I don't think your proof actually works. You seem to show that each $k-i$ in the denominator divides some $a_k-a_j$ in the numerator. But what if several different $k-i$'s divide one and the same $a_k-a_j$? Then only one of them would properly get cancelled.

Comment: ohh true ok, thank you!